# Send event between iPhones

Tags: iphone, events

I want to create a social interaction application which sends an event to each other. For example, if user1 shakes the phone, user2 will be notified in real-time. Could you help me out where to start?

I am working in iOS7 using Xcode 5.0

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is really far to vague...

Do want to know something about:
- push notifications
- client-server functionality
- iPhone development in general
- detecting motions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Push Notifications provide a solution in this regard. The following tutorial  was very helpful.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/

I followed the tutorial and I could implement my application!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bluetooth or Bump or something self implemented.
Try search for a GameKit tutorial (Bluetooth) or visit [Bump repo](https://github.com/bumptech/bump-api-ios)